# Session login with Passport (Node.js/Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, passport.js

How to manage session logins with Passport (Express)? By session logins I mean: an authenticated user should not have to resend credentials at each request.

In the following example, `myStrategy.authenticate()` keeps being called even if the user previously authenticated.

```
var express = require( "express" );
var session = require( "express-session" );
var passport = require( "passport" );
var app = express();

var myStrategy = function(){ this.name = "mystrategy"; };
myStrategy.prototype.authenticate = function( req ) {
  console.log( "called" );
  this.success( "user" );
};

passport.use( new myStrategy() );
passport.serializeUser( function( id, cb ){ cb( null, id ); });
passport.deserializeUser( function( id, cb ){ cb( null, id ); });

app
  .use( session({ secret: "hello", resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }) )
  .use( passport.initialize() )
  .use( passport.session() )
  .get( "/", passport.authenticate( "mystrategy" ), function( req, res ) {
    res.send( "OK" );
  })
  .listen( 80 );
```

It seems `passport.session()` retrieves `req.user` from `req.session.passport.user`, but `passport.authenticate()` fires even when `req.user` is defined, which defeats the whole point.

Comment: You have to check yourself if the user is authenticated (by using for example `req.isAuthenticated()`). Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888214/why-is-passport-serializeuser-executed-on-each-request/24892203#24892203) I answered. The question is very similar to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to dissociate the login action (on the login page) from the authentication checks (on the protected pages):

```
.get( "/auth", passport.authenticate( "mystrategy" ), function( req, res ) {
  res.send( "OK" );
})
.get( "/private", function( req, res ) {
  if ( req.isAuthenticated() ) {
    res.send( "Private data" );
  }
})
```